# Whether to use a through model in a M2M relationship

Tags: django, django-models

I am adding a user's education to his userprofile. A user may have multiple entries for his education. Should I be using a basic M2M relationship, such as --

```
class Education(models.Model):
    school = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    class_year = models.IntegerField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True)
    degree = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    educations = models.ManyToManyField(Education)
```

Or should I be using a through model for this relationship? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@manji](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6318589/whether-to-use-a-through-model-in-a-m2m-relationship/6318635#6318635) is correct: Django will create a mapping table whether or not you use `through`.

To provide an example of why you might want to add more fields to the intermediary, or `through` table:
You could have a field in the `through` table to track whether or not that particular education represented the final school the person attended:

```
class Education(models.Model):
    ...

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ...
    educations = models.ManyToManyField(Education, through='EduUsrRelation')

class EducationUserRelation(models.Model):
    education = models.ForeignKey(Education)
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    is_last_school_attended = models.BooleanField()
```

Answer (score 2):

Django will [create automatically an intermediary](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#id1) join table to represent the `ManyToMany` relation between the 2 models.

If you want to add more fields to this table, provide your own table (i.e Model) via `through` attribute, otherwise you don't need to.